# Fire function before window resizes content on orientation change?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, resize, orientation

so I've been building myself a mobile webapp and am trying to hide the reshuffle of the layout after the user has rotated the phone (i have a portrait and a landscape layout set by js).

I had thought that I should be able to set `$('body').display = "none";` when the resize fires and fade the body back in after a second or so, however the shuffle still happens before the `display = "none"` kicks in.

Is there any way to fire a function as soon as the page rotates so that i can hide the reshuffling elements? I have also tried onorientationchange listeners but they seem to fire directly after the event has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

you can delay the reshuffling with a timeout:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $('body').hide();
   setTimeout(function(){
      reshuffle();
      $('body').show();
   }, 100);//100ms
});
```

Comment: thanks for the input, thats pretty much exactly the code im currently using, the browser seems to render the new orientations layout with the old css values before the .hide has time to be fired by the resize(so for about 50ms i can see the unshuffled layout), i think this might not be doable somehow =s

Comment: thanks, i attached this to my onorientationchange event instead of resize just to give it another try and it seems to work slightly better, maybe 50% of the time it looks clean and tidy. It also helps to set any container elements to your bg color so that the default white bg doesnt show through.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
$.when($('body').hide()).then(function() {
     $(window).resize(function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
             reshuffle();
         }, 100);//100ms
     });
});
```

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I will give this a try however i dont think it will solve the problem as the .hide doesnt actually kick in till after the resize event (unless .then can queue up the existing resize), so (if im thinking of how your code will work in the right way) it will  "fire resize after the phone is rotated > detect that body has hidden > then wait for a resize > fire a delayed layout function?

Comment: The way I understood your problem was that you wanted to reshuffle after the body was hidden, and I believe that does this (unless I'm mistaken)

Comment: i dont quite have time to test it right now but will let you know when i put it into action. it does look like it will do the job, the problem that i seem to be facing is that the browser on a phone isnt fast enough to keep pace with the orientation and hide the content before it hits landscape.